# Foreman Installation on Raspberry fails due to missing capybara

Tags: ruby, raspberry-pi, raspbian, foreman

We are attempting to install foreman on a raspberry as a demo for installation on larger machines such as the cubietruck. We have problems building the foreman-installer from source:

```
bundle install --without mysql2 pg test --path vendor
Your Gemfile lists the gem gettext_i18n_rails_js (>= 0.0.8) more than once.
You should probably keep only one of them.
While it's not a problem now, it could cause errors if you change the version of just one of them later.
Your Gemfile lists the gem gettext (~> 2.0) more than once.
You should probably keep only one of them.
While it's not a problem now, it could cause errors if you change the version of just one of them later.
Your Gemfile lists the gem locale (<= 2.0.9) more than once.
You should probably keep only one of them.
While it's not a problem now, it could cause errors if you change the version of just one of them later.
Your Gemfile lists the gem minitest (~> 4.7) more than once.
You should probably keep only one of them.
While it's not a problem now, it could cause errors if you change the version of just one of them later.
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/........
Fetching additional metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
Resolving dependencies...............................................
Could not find gem 'capybara (~> 2.0.0) ruby' in the gems available on this
machine.
```

We have already manually installed capybara using gem and can locally see it:

```
sudo gem list

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

bundler (1.6.2)
capybara (2.0.0)
childprocess (0.5.3)
ffi (1.9.3)
mime-types (2.3)
mini_portile (0.6.0)
multi_json (1.10.1)
nokogiri (1.6.2.1)
rack (1.5.2)
rack-test (0.6.2)
rubyzip (1.1.4)
selenium-webdriver (2.42.0)
websocket (1.0.7)
xpath (1.0.0)
```

Any ideas what we are missing?

Regards

Stefan

Comment: Could you include your Gemfile?

Comment: I'm a little surprised at `'capybara (~> 2.0.0) ruby'` ... I would've expected to see `'capybara (~> 2.0.0)`